# How may I add a faded colour effect (screenshot shown)

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-relativelayout, fade

Hey I would like to know how i can added such a `faded color effect` to my layout any help is appreciated. An example here:

[image: https://lh6.ggpht.com/m3pFLge29-CgEmjHu_X_exurwNL4TqTlMedvFne7IANudDle-bFaqZl0BwKAG19pO-1L=h900]

Thanks

Comment: Don't add, just use already faded layout to show in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) with your desired gradient and set it as a background for your *information* view at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setAlpha()** method to adjust alpha level for your views and thereby get a faded effect.For handling this in xml you can use android:alpha attribute for your view.

Comment: Yes, but that would set the fade for the whole. As shown in the screenshot, I'd like to know how I can have it darker on the bottom and faded as you go up.

Comment: You can add a masking layer above your view covering it, may be a frame layout, set the background of the frame layout to a custom created drawable element,say a gradient xml in which the alpha level varies from bottom to top.